# How do I get the width & height of each grid cell in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, methods, gridbaglayout, column-width, row-height

Everywhere I look for help with GridBagLayout only helps with GridBagConstraints. I understand that part completely, it's the methods inside GridBagLayout that confuse me.

So I realized that the fields columnWidths and rowHeights are for overriding GridBagLayout's cell widths and heights, and are null until set by user. (I have implemented those fields in my program below) So how do I get the ACTUAL width and height of the cell?

[image]

I'm basically trying to override the paint method of the container in order to draw a grid that show where each cell begins and ends (where gridwidth and gridheight is irrelevant). The one thing that looks applicable is getLayoutInfo(Container parent, int sizeflag), but GridBagLayoutInfo has no methods or fields, and I have no idea what it means by sizeflag.

EDIT:
This is basically the grid I would like to draw, but of course I want to make sure it would work on any container where gridlayout is the layout manager. These are the actual gridx and gridy coordinates highlighted in red. I just don't know how to get the values I need to the paint method.
[image]

Comment: If you cant find something without overriding, try finding the combined height of the individual buttons(using a simple loop) and the combined width of each individual button. For example, all the keys from ctrl to the right arrow key have a certain length, add those up. Next find the height from the right arrow key to the delete key, and add those all up. Store those values in variables (x, y).

Comment: This won't work. Each button has a minimum gridwidth of 4. I want to create a grid where there's a line at every gridx and gridy coordinate. All 61 gridx coordinates, and 12 gridy coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayout has a method [getLayoutDimensions()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getLayoutDimensions()) which returns array of two arrays. First array is column widths and second array is row heights. This method considers insets set in GridBagConstrains of each cell to be part of the cell.

I know this question is stale but I ran into simmilar problem recently and found it while searching for solution.